# How to fix Cloth Simulation from this odd compression

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

The objective of this simulation was to just have the cloth hang down so part of the tent door is open and part is hidden behind the tarp.
Originally it was a simple plane, I have recently solidified it (0.01m) after reading some tips and answers from other questions on StackExchange but this did not solve it.

I will provide all the images showing my modifier stack, cloth physics settings, collision settings and the static pin group as well as the blend file below.

[image: Deformed Cloth]

[image: Original PLane]

[image: Cloth Settings]

[image: Collision settings]

[image: Static Pin Group]

[image: Modifier Stack]

I have had to delete the bakes for the simulation due to file size for blend exchange.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fabric curls up like this or explodes the collision detection is usually to blame. But it takes only a few steps to fix this.

1. **Add a floor**: Add a plane, scale it up, add & apply a *Subdivision modifier* (`3` levels, type: *Simple*), and add a *Collision* physics to it
2. **Fix the door**:

   1. Swap the order of the modifiers to 1. *Subdivison*, 2. *Cloth* ←→ 3. *Solidify*
   2. Change the levels of the *Subdivision* modifier: `2` (Viewport) and `2` (Render)
   3. In the Physics tab, use the *Silk preset*. For some reason, your door plane is way too stiff. (Presets are in the drop-down menu right next to the Cloth section; the icon with 3 dots and lines).
   4. Change the *Distance* of *Object Collision* and *Self Collision* from 15 cm to 5 mm (`0.005 m`). The default value of 15 cm is too high for your tent in real-world size.
3. **Optimization**: Remove the *Collision* from the 2 branches objects. It has no effect on the result since the fabric slides only briefly over the left branch and is attached to the right branch anyway. But the removal will speed up the simulation.
4. **Run the simulation**. It should run smoothly. If you get single vertices that go crazy for a second ("spikes"/"fireworks") increase the Cloth → *Quality Steps* from `5` to `9` and they should calm down.

[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: Apologies I wasn't at my desk yesterday so I didn't see notification but thank you very much, I followed all the steps and it has fixed the simulation. I will remember the tips you have mentioned for future simulations as well. Appreciate your help, and anyone else with this problem, this is the fix for it :) ill upvote and accept this as the answer, hope you enjoy the holidays!